# JavaFX moving chess figures

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I am creating chess game and I want to move one node to another column and row.

[image: ScreenShot]

I created a class method to move the Pawn.

```
public void MovePawn(GridPane gridPane,int col,int row)
{
    int co = 0; //this counter exist because the figures are above the chessfield.
    for (Node node : gridPane.getChildren()) {
        if (GridPane.getColumnIndex(node) == col && GridPane.getRowIndex(node) == row) {
            if(co == 1) {
                gridPane.getChildren().remove(node);
                gridPane.add(this.IMG,this.x,this.y + 2);
            }
            co = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works and figure moves to coordinates but i get a bunch of errors.
Why?

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator$VetoableIteratorDecorator.checkForComodification(VetoableListDecorator.java:714)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator$VetoableIteratorDecorator.hasNext(VetoableListDecorator.java:682)
    at sample.Figures.blackPawn.MovePawn(blackPawn.java:27)
    at sample.Main.lambda$start$0(Main.java:49)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I don't see how this moves the node though and why you don't exit the loop with `break;` after you found the appropriate node. To simply move a node, it's sufficient to adjust the `rowIndex` and `columnIndex` btw, no need to modify the child list: `GridPane.setRowIndex(node, newRowIndex); GridPane.setColumnIndex(node, newColumnIndex);`

Comment: you didnt see how it moves because i didnt show the full code there is also the main class where eventhandler for "pawn" is situated.i edited the loop to set rather than delete and add thanks for the help!